# Why does a Content type revert to default content type on its own?

Tags: 2010, development, content-type, sharepoint-server

This is a large, multi-disciplinary site that is routinely grouping and filtering documents by content type. If the content type is changing on their own this is going to break our views and make all of our content appear in the wrong place.

What would make the Content Types change "on their own"?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have really any issue, just asking the question...can a content type revert back to default by its own.

I never see any issue with content type, where its go back to default one unless some body change it, manually or view workflow corruption etc.

If you have issue, please share the more error detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. Created custom content type for documents, it works for new documents , works for some documents already in, but for majority of documents for unknown reasons it will revert back to basic document in aprox. 2 seconds. Default library is being used *(yea i know..), Tried to delete default document content type - cant it is in used *(1k+docs, sight). I have set mine as default and hide "default one" - again the same result works like magic for new files but not for already existing.. I haven't found out why it is happening - my initial theory was that it is due locked documents - false